# Student discounts on flights to the US?

Tags: air-travel, study

Are there any offers or discount for students flying to the US for education?

Comment: Good question (+1) but I think airlines primarily rely on other mechanisms for price discrimination (booking early, flying at inconvenient times, etc.) The logic is that students (and other price-sensitive customers) would take the cheaper flights and the airline can still maximize profit on seats that are in demand.

Comment: From where you are going to flight?

Answer (score 5):

There are actually sites dedicated to discounts for student travel:

- [StudentUniverse](http://www.studentuniverse.com/)
- [STA Travel](http://www.statravel.com)

I could not find the major US Carriers advertising this on their websites but it is possible that they might offer such discounts if called for reservation directly.

[KLM](http://www.klm.com/home/us/en#g_np_sa-page=1&sa=2) for example doesn't offer any student fares.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Student Universe](http://www.studentuniverse.com/) several times in the past. I have used [STA Travels](http://www.statravel.com/) once as well (for a EURail Pass). The only restriction for both is that you must provide your school ID to them in order to hold a valid account.

As long as you can do that, they have some pretty good deals, especially at the last minute. Beware that sometimes Student Universe will show you tickets which you cannot book if you click on them stating that the "offer" is not available anymore. But I can vouch that they are extremely trustworthy will excellent customer support. STA travels offers discounts for group tickets as well!

Also, I do not work for either of these companies.